# How to draw contours around black areas in pixeld image?

Tags: python, opencv

i am quite new to Python and i try to write some code for image analysing.
Here is my initial image:
[Initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dJny.jpg)

After splitting the image in to the rgb channels, converting in to gradient, using a threshold and merging them back together i get the following image:
[Gradient/Threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkWX8.jpg)

Now i have to draw contours around the black areas and get the size of the surrounded areas. I just dont know how to do it, since my trials with find/draw.contours in opencv are not succesfull at all.

Maybe someone also knows an easier way to get that from the initial image.
Hope someone can help me here!

I am coding in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try [adaptive thresholding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding) on the grayscale image of the input image.
[image: My output]

Also play with the last two parameters of the adaptive thresholding. You will find good results as I have shown in the image. (Tip: Create trackbar and play with value, this will be quick and easy method to get best values of these params.)

Comment: I tried the adaptive threshold already. The problem is, that there are still unwanted pixels in there and the result changes from image to image. I need a method to work for many different images. They all work really well with my gradient and threshholding. With the adaptive thresholding I have to change the parameter for every image.

Comment: How can I add another image so you can see what i mean with "different" images. I have to analyse almost 200 images and i dont want to search for params all the time.

Comment: To add more images, you can simply upload images on your google drive folder and share the link here.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am quite new here, so I don´t know all of this stuff. Here are some more:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NH3zxf8ktxqAbhz4kkSpikkLxys8HDaz?usp=sharing